# Activation error occured while trying to get instance of type Database, key "ConnString"

Tags: c#, sharepoint-2010, enterprise-library-5

Am trying to connect to database from Microsoft Project Server database with Enterprise Library 5.0. I included all the DLL references and able to deploy the application without any issues. However, when am trying to create a project its failing with the following error message:

"Activation error occured while trying to get instance of type Database, key "ConnString""

Web.config file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>  
  <configSections>
    <section name="dataConfiguration" 
             type="Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data.Configuration.DatabaseSettings, Microsoft.Practices.EnterpriseLibrary.Data,
              Version = 5.0.414.0, Culture = neutral, PublicKeyToken = 31bf3856ad364e35"
             requirePermission="true"/>  
  </configSections>    
  <dataConfiguration defaultDatabase="ConnString" />  
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnString" 
         connectionString="Data Source=(localhost);Initial Catalog=MyDB;User ID=XYZ;Password=XYZ;" 
         providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

What am I missing ?